# What software does atom parsing MPEG files?

Tags: mpeg

[image]
I'm looking for this software but don't know the name.

Software that atom parsing MPEG files

Comment: Are you looking for software that does that kind of thing (showing the various atoms/boxes in a structured way), or are you asking for the name of that exact software?

Comment: I need any similar software

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reluctant to provide specific recommendations, so I'll suggest some approaches to solving the problem:

- a search for "MPEG4 validation" or "ISOBMFF validation" will probably get you to something like MP4Box, which has an online version - https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/test/filereader.html
  (and you can self-host), command line tools like https://github.com/amarghosh/mp4viewer and similar commercial options.
- you could also use https://github.com/MPEGGroup/isobmff or similar software to build something yourself.